# Do electrons in a CRT emit radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism

According to electrodynamics, accelerating charged particles would emit electromagnetic energy as radiation. Isn't it applicable to the accelerated electrons within a cathode ray tube? Do they give out radiation? If yes, what is the nature of it?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason that CRTs were/are constructed with leaded-glass to reduce the x-ray emissions in your living room.

Answer (score 1):

X-rays are produced when the electrons hit the screen.   But the glass envelope is leaded, so little if any radiation escapes.

Comment: Also, since the deceleration vector is parallel to the direction of the electron beam and the electrons are non-relativistic, I believe that most of the radiation is directed not forward toward the TV viewer but perpendicular to this direction.